# Calculating walking distance for user over time

Tags: gps, location, distance

I'm trying to track the distance a user has moved over time in my application using the GPS. I have the basic idea in place, so I store the previous location and when a new GPS location is sent I calculate the distance between them, and add that to the total distance. So far so good.

There are two big issues with this simple implementation:

1. Since the GPS is inacurate, when the user moves, the GPS points will not be a straight line but more of a "zig zag" pattern making it look like the user has moved longer than he actually have moved.
2. Also a accuracy problem. If the phone just lays on the table and polls GPS possitions, the answer is usually a couple of meters different every time, so you see the meters start accumulating even when the phone is laying still.

Both of these makes the tracking useless of coruse, since the number I'm providing is nowwhere near accurate enough.

But I guess that this problem is solvable since there are a lot of fitness trackers and similar out there that does track distance from GPS. I guess they do some kind of interpolation between the GPS values or something like that? I guess that won't be 100% accurate either, but probably good enough for my usage.

So what I'm after is basically a algorithm where I can put in my GPS positions, and get as good approximation of distance travelled as possible.

Note that I cannot presume that the user will follow roads, so I cannot use the Google Distance Matrix API or similar for this.

Comment: try to make a single line form "starting point" to "end point". This will avoid you the zig-zag pattern and allow to measure a distance.

Comment: I can't assume that the users moves in a straight line from A to B either, but I guess that I will have to "smooth" out the positions from GPS in some way.

Comment: I think the problem is just the error threshould. i.e. calculate after subtracting or adding some value (which is the error threshold). If the change in x or y values exeeds some threshould, then the user actually changed his walk path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem with the position data that is produced by GPS receivers.  A typical consumer grade receiver that I have used has a position accuracy defined as a CEP of 2.5 metres.  This means that for a stationary receiver in a "perfect" sky view environment over time 50% of the position fixes will lie within a circle with a radius of 2.5 metres.  If you look at the position that the receiver reports it appears to wander at random around the true position sometimes moving a number of metres away from its true location.  If you simply integrate the distance moved between samples then you will get a very large apparent distance travelled.for a stationary device.

A simple algorithm that I have used quite successfully for a vehicle odometer function is as follows

```
for(;;)
{
    Stored_Position = Current_Position ;
    do 
    {
       Distance_Moved = Distance_Between( Current_Position, Stored_Position ) ;
    } while ( Distance_Moved < MOVEMENT_THRESHOLD ) ;

    Cumulative_Distance += Distance_Moved ;
}
```

The value of MOVEMENT_THRESHOLD will have an effect on the accuracy of the final result.  If the value is too small then some of the random wandering performed by the stationary receiver will be included in the final result.  If the value is too large then the path taken will be approximated to a series of straight lines each of which is as long as the threshold value.  The extra distance travelled by the receiver as its path deviates from this straight line segment will be missed.

The accuracy of this approach, when compared with the vehicle odometer, was pretty good.  How well it works with a pedestrian would have to be tested.  The problem with people is that they can make much sharper turns than a vehicle resulting in larger errors from the straight line approximation.  There is also the perennial problem with sky view obscuration and signal multipath caused by buildings, vehicles etc. that can induce positional errors of 10s of metres.

Comment: I tested this out and it works like a charm, and is accurate enough for what I'm using it for. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: No Problem.  It has worked for me for over 10 years and has the advantage of being simple enough to not use up valuable processing time on my 8MHz processor.